# Use Intel Rapid Storage Technology with a secondary PCIe RAID card

Tags: raid, raid-1, intel-rst

I have Intel's RST on motherboard using RAID1 (2x2TB) and a boot drive. Trying to add another RAID1 (2x3TB) has failed since RST is limited to 2.2TB for RAID1. Now I've bought another RAID card in order to add said drives. The problem is that BIOS sees only the new drives and for some reason doesn't allow me to boot from the original disks. The new RAID card is SYBA SY-PEX40039; returning that...

But now I'm wondering whether adding another RAID card is at all possible with RST. And if so, what cards are recommended?

Thanks

Comment: Can you disable RST on your motherboard thru the BIOS? How about disabling the detection of the drives by your BIOS?

Comment: Can't disable, but why would I want to? It hosts RAID1 + boot disk. Haven't found anything on drive detection in BIOS. FYI, its an HP desktop.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this question? I'm finding it hard to understand exactly what your setup is and what your end game is. Be specific. What model HP do you have, what model are the drives and what model is the 2nd RAID controller.